# Nested inner class in Jersey / JAX-RS

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have this resource which is located perfectly:

```
@Path("/adoptable")
public class AdoptableAnimalsResource {

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String get() 
  {
    return "dogs";
  }
}
```

**Now, how can I turn this class into a nested inner class?**
 For example,

```
public class Grouper
{
  @Path("/adoptable")
  public class AdoptableAnimalsResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String get() 
    {
      return "dogs";
    }
  }
}
```

When I try it, I get a 404 Not Found error, suggesting that Jersey is not considering the inner class as a resource.

Comment: 'Nested inner' is a tautology. 'Inner' is sufficient.

Comment: It was an intentional tautology, but thanks for pointing it out. It was intentional because people refer to the item in different ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [Sub-Resource Locators](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2184). Basically, you will have a method in `Grouper` class, which will instantiate the `AdoptableAnimalsResource` class. The `AdoptableAnimalsResource` should not have a `@Path` annotation. It could but it will be ignored. It's methods can have sub-resource `@Path`s. The method in the `Grouper` class should have `@Path` that identities the `AdoptableAnimalsResource` sub-resource.

So it might look something like

```
@Path("/groups")
public class Grouper {

    @Path("/adoptable")
    public AdoptableAnimalsResource animalSubResource() {
        return new AdoptableAnimalsResource();
    }

    public class AdoptableAnimalsResource {

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public String get() {
            return "dogs";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the path to simply be "/adoptable" without the extra part. Will this example produce "/groups/adoptable"?

Comment: Yes. Then make the path `"/"` for the `Grouper` class. But it _must_ be annotated with `@Path` to make it an accessible resource class